# What is penalty for not closing Delaware C-Corp?

Tags: corporate-law, incorporation, corporate-tax-laws, accounting

I'm a non-US citizen and started Delaware C-Corp in Sep 2021, now I have to pay $400 franchise tax, accountant cost, and closing cost. I don't close this C-corp officially and In the future, If I have to start another one, Can I do it, or first I have to pay all franchise tax for this one?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It would probably be on-topic on money, but I don't see that it is off-topic here,. Bering on-topic elsewhere is not a valid reason to close here.